# Android App, Get Json data

Tags: php, android, json

I want to make an app that receives data from a json file. And when it receives new items it has to make a sound. How can i do this?

I've been searching around but i couldn't find a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a great tutorial [here](http://hmkcode.com/android-parsing-json-data/) covering REST services and JSON data.
It's quite comprehensive and should get you on the right track.

Comment: How can i make it that when there is a new item, there will be a sound?

Comment: If you want the sound in app you'll need to use [Media Playback](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html). If you want the sound to play when the app is closed you'll need to look into implementing push notifications

Comment: Could you edit your answer to include the relevant parts of your link? That will guard against the link going dead, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go to the library route, [RetroFit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) is an amazing Android/Java library for parsing JSON data. You would make a call to your server for the JSON, and after the call you would trigger the media playback code using Retrofit's onResponse method.

For example:

```
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<Version> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    if (response.isSuccess()) {
    // TODO check if received data is new
    // TODO Media playback code 
    }
}
@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
      Log.d("Callback", " Throwable is " + t);
      }
```

Retrofit is very powerful so I highly recommend you read the documentation for it. You can find more information about the library and how to use it [here](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).